# type hinting rosmsgs in callbacks?

Tags: rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Trying to prepare proper documentation for a code review and I wanted to use type hinting, however Im getting errors (expectedly) when type hinting for rosmsgs during function callbacks...

Wanted to know if anyone else has experienced this and any workarounds?

```
def on_action_done(self, goal_status: actionlib_msgs/GoalStatus, result: rows/RowsResult) -> None:
def on_action_done(self, goal_status: GoalStatus, result: RowsResult) -> None:
```

Neither is working, both are throwing NameError exceptions.

python3.7.4

ROS1: noetic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/369651/type-hinting-rosmsgs-in-callbacks?/) by [rbed23](https://answers.ros.org/users/64718/rbed23/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2021-01-15

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-01-16**:\

> python3.7.4

have you built Noetic from source? The default Python 3 version supported on Ubuntu Focal by Noetic is `3.8` according to [REP-3](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#noetic-ninjemys-may-2020-may-2025).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> however Im getting errors (expectedly) when type hinting for rosmsgs during function callbacks...

why *expectedly*?

ROS msgs in Python are Python modules containing (mainly) a class. So you should be able to treat them as such.

As long as the packages are on the `PYTHONPATH`, I'd expect things to work.

> `goal_status: actionlib_msgs/GoalStatus`

this doesn't look like a proper Python type name to me.

shouldn't it at least be `actionlib_msgs.msg.GoalStatus`?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rbed23](https://answers.ros.org/users/64718/rbed23/) on 2021-01-21**:
actionlib.GoalStatus works...

I just needed to use the msg imports i.e. result: RowsResult, target: TrackedTarget

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-01-22**:\

> actionlib.GoalStatus works...

this confuses me a little.

Is that a verbatim copy-paste of the type identifier, or should it be `actionlib_msgs.msg.GoalStatus`?

The following fails for me: `python -c 'from actionlib import GoalStatus'`.

**Comment by [rbed23](https://answers.ros.org/users/64718/rbed23/) on 2021-01-23**:
(robot) me@BenderInspiron:~/robot/ros_src$ python -c "from actionlib import GoalStatus; print(GoalStatus)"
<class 'actionlib_msgs.msg._GoalStatus.GoalStatus'>

Im working in a venv and I have the setup.bash file sourced...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-01-24**:
Isn't that because almost all top-level modules in `actionlib` themselves `import GoalStatus` from `actionlib_msgs`?

The type is really declared and defined in `actionlib_msgs`.

if you're doing this to be clear about which types get used in your code, it would make more sense to me to use the appropriate (ie: correct) type definition, instead of one which happens to be exposed via a transitive dependency.

**Comment by [rbed23](https://answers.ros.org/users/64718/rbed23/) on 2021-01-24**:
sure, if you want/need to separately `import actionlib_msgs` explicitly for that, in addition to `import actionlib` then go ahead :thumbsup:

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-01-24**:
So you're going to go through the effort of providing Python with typing hints, but then are OK with passing it the wrong type?

`GoalStatus` is part of the action definition. It's a message. It comes from the `actionlib_msgs` package.

Relying on another package to bring in your dependency is actually an anti-pattern, and should be avoided.